# Activate Binary if specific pairs of binaries equal 2

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, integer-programming

I have a problem formulation with binary variables `x1`,`x2`,`x3`,`x4`.

I want another binary variable `y` to be required to equal 1 under the following circumstances:

`y=1` when `x1 + x2 = 2` or `x3 + x4 = 2`

The overall problem formulation generally penalizes `y=1` so I'm OK with methods that allow `y=1` under other circumstances, but ideally `y=1` iff `x1 + x2 = 2` or `x3 + x4 = 2`

Answer (score 7):

You want to enforce
$$((x_1 \land x_2) \lor (x_3 \land x_4)) \implies y.$$
Rewriting in conjunctive normal form yields
$$(\lnot x_1 \lor \lnot x_2 \lor y) \land (\lnot x_3 \lor \lnot x_4 \lor y),$$
which immediately yields linear constraints
\begin{align}
(1 - x_1) + (1 - x_2) + y &\ge 1\\
(1 - x_3) + (1 - x_4) + y &\ge 1
\end{align}
Equivalently,
\begin{align}
y&\ge x_1+x_2-1\\
y&\ge x_3+x_4-1
\end{align}

The converse implication is
$$y \implies ((x_1 \land x_2) \lor (x_3 \land x_4)).$$
Rewriting in conjunctive normal form yields
$$(\lnot y \lor x_1 \lor x_3) \land (\lnot y \lor x_1 \lor x_4) \land (\lnot y \lor x_2 \lor x_3) \land (\lnot y \lor x_2 \lor x_4),$$
which immediately yields linear constraints
\begin{align}
(1 - y) + x_1 + x_3 &\ge 1\\
(1 - y) + x_1 + x_4 &\ge 1\\
(1 - y) + x_2 + x_3 &\ge 1\\
(1 - y) + x_2 + x_4 &\ge 1
\end{align}
Equivalently,
\begin{align}
y&\le x_1+x_3 \\
y&\le x_1+x_4 \\
y&\le x_2+x_3 \\
y&\le x_2+x_4
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks @robpratt.  Using your formulation knocked my IP from 1.4M binaries to 1M binaries.  Root relaxation on gurobi is the same as the previous formulation so things look legit thus far...

Answer (score 4):

Rob's answer covers the "if" case. For the "only if" case, add two more binary variables $z_1$ and $z_2$ plus the constraints $$2z_1 \le x_1 + x_2$$ $$2x_2 \le x_3 + x_4$$and $$y \le z_1 + z_2.$$That plus Rob's two constraints gets you to $y=1$ if and only if either $x_1 + x_2=2$ or $x_3 + x_4=2.$

Comment: Your method is (close to) what I've done already.  But given the scale of the problem, adding two more binary variables (multiplied by about 50,000 cases) is adding some serious solve time.  So I think I'll try out Rob's method and see if it gets the desired effect

Comment: I think you meant $=2$ instead of $=1$ in the last two equations.  Also, I modified my answer to enforce the converse, without introducing new variables.

Comment: @RobPratt Oops, yes. I've fixed that.